# AngularJS - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider userService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS to create a simple signup and login form for my backend.

Here my files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="bookApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Book Wishlist Application</title>

<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>


<style>

    li {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Book Wishlist Application</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('bookApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'bookController'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupController'
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateurl: 'partials/index.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

controllers.js

```
var bookController = angular.module('bookController', []);

bookController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService', function ($scope, $http, userService) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        userService.login(
            $scope.email, $scope.password,
            function(response){
                $location.path('/');
            },
            function(response){
                alert('Something went wrong with the login process. Try again later!');
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.password = '';

    if(userService.checkIfLoggedIn())
        $location.path('/');
}]);
bookController.controller('SignupController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService', function ($scope, $http, userService) {
    $scope.signup = function(){
        userService.signup(
            $scope.name, $scope.email, $scope.password,
            function(response){
                alert('Account Creato');
                $location.path('/');
            },
            function(response){
                alert('Something went wrong with the signup process. Try again later.');
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.password = '';
    $scope.email = '';

    if( userService.checkIfLoggedIn()){
        $location.path('/');
    }
}]);
bookController.controller('MailController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

}]);
```

services.js

```
var bookServices = angular.module('bookServices', [
    'LocalStorageModule'
]);

bookServices.factory('userService', ['$http', 'localStorageService', function ($http, localStorageService) {

    function checkIfLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorageService.get('token')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function signUp(name, email, password, onSuccess, onError) {
        $http.post('/api/auth/signup', {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                localStorageService.set('token', response.data.token);
                onSuccess(response);
            }, function () {
                onError(response);
            });
    }

    function login(email, password, onSuccess, onError) {
        $http.post('api/auth/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                localStorageService.set('token', response.data.token);
                onSuccess(response);
            }, function (response) {
                onError(response);
            });
    }

    function logout() {
        localStorageService.remove('token');
    }

    function getCurrentToken() {
        return localStorageService.get('token');
    }

    return {
        checkIfLoggedIn: checkIfLoggedIn,
        signUp: signUp,
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        getCurrentToken: getCurrentToken
    }
}]);
```

the problem is that the console says:

> Unknown provider: userServiceProvider <- userService <-
>   LoginController

I tried to pass it as dependency of the Controller but I get:

> Failed to instantiate module bookApp due to: Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=b...)
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
>       at http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:134
>       at r (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
>       at g (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:222)
>       at http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:391
>       at r (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
>       at g (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:222)
>       at db (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:246)
>       at c (http://laravelangular.app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register `bookServices` with `bookApp` module in app.js assuming you "pass it as dependency of the Controller"

`var app = angular.module('bookApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'bookServices',
    'bookController'
]);`

Comment: It worked and in the mail app.js file is the best place form me

Comment: @Noppey :  Say it again ;)

Comment: It works because it's the Angular way to put components to the separated modules.
@christian-giupponi already **pass it as dependency of the Controller** so the last piece missing was to add it to the app module.

Comment: My question is more like: module A is created with dependency of module B and C. 
I was under the impression that module B cannot use module C because it's injected in some module that happens to also depend on module C. 

So I'm surprised that this would work, but apparently it does. I want to know why :)

Answer (score 1):

Your userService factory lives in bookServices module. This module is not injected in the bookcontroller module. Use:

```
var bookController = angular.module('bookController', ['bookServices']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your userService and controllers are in separate module. try to inject ur **bookServices** service module to **bookController** module

```
var bookController = angular.module('bookController', ['bookServices']);
```

Comment: look at the time stamp. while i'm writing the answer other answer been post